# Do I have to pay Virginia Tax on capital gains from real estate sale out of state?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, virginia

I sold a residential building lot in Florida in 2017. I am a resident of VA. Do I have to report those gains to VA for taxes? I did for my federal and paid the tax.

Comment: Does Florida tax real estate profits? Did you pay them?

Comment: Just absolutely as an aside, I think it's very sensible and "modern" to simply use one's first name on sites like this - rather than the faintly ridiculous ubiquitous tradition of a nom de plume.

Comment: @Fattie: That's the name your mom gave you? :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you pay state taxes on capital gains in both the state of the sale, and the state you reside in.  In most (all?) cases, you can deduct the taxes paid in the state of sale from the state of residence, but since Florida has a 0% capital gains tax this doesn't matter.